# Why can't I launch R in server using vim R plugin?

Tags: r, vim

My local computer platform is this:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
Release:    8.1
Codename:   jessie
```

Where I have installed vim-r-plugin and it works well.

Now I have some project needs to work on server which turns out a platform of:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

In this server I can't launch R through `\rf` as I usually do on my local computer. My question is how to launch R from my server platform. Do I need to install vim-r-plugin again in the server Ubuntu platform?

Comment: Yes, you need to install the plugin locally on the server you're working on.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What input do you try and what output do you receive?